# Jenkins - how to set Variable value into the zip file name?

Tags: jenkins

I have a variable, set as global environment,  which outputs the timestamp.

```
echo "Current build version: ${BUILDVERSION}"
```

***Current build version: 20211117-114343***

Now I want to add this value to **zip** step for setting the zip file name and I check the content of the zip file.

```
            zip zipFile: 'test_${BUILDVERSION}.zip'
            sh 'zipinfo -1 test_${BUILDVERSION}.zip'
```

ZIP is not created properly: `test_${BUILDVERSION}.zip` while zipinfo takes this value properly. `zipinfo -1 test_20211117-114343.zip`

Can you please assist what I do wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Use double quotes.  Read about [String interpolation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation) in Groovy

`zip zipFile: "test_${BUILDVERSION}.zip"`

Comment: @AndreyDonald you're welcome.  Heed the security warnings as it relates to String interpolation, especially if your passing user data ( parameters, etc ) directly into an `sh`  `bat` or `powershell` command.  Should be fine with a global variable `BUILDVERSION` though

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very useful. If I may ask you very shortly what link you would suggest me to go through for uploading my zip file to the Artifactory through the Jenkins? I need to publish to Artifactory, also using the declarative pipeline. Thanks a lot, all the best!